# How to put @ symbol in jquery code in mvc5 razor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have longitude and lattitude positions and now I want to show the longitude and lattitude in google maps ... This is a link through which we can show it for free ... https://www.google.com/maps/@30,70z ...

```
$('btn-location').click(function () {
        var lon = $('longitude').text(); // value here is 70
        var lat = $('latitude').text(); // value here is 30

        window.location.replace("https://www.google.com/maps/@" + lat + "," + lon + "z");
    });
```

Here is the code using jquery but I am getting error on @ symbol ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ is special character in Razor pages you need to escape it. Just use `@@`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code snippet: @@ is the escape character for @ in Razor views.

```
$("#btn-location").click(function () {
       var lon = $("#longitude").text(); // value here is 70
       var lat = $("#latitude").text(); // value here is 30
       window.location.replace("https://www.google.com/maps/@@" + lat + "," + lon + "z");
     });
```

Got the result: https://www.google.com/maps/@30,70z